# ommission of "there" in wh-clause

Tags: sentence-structure, pronouns

> It does not matter how many days there are in a week.

Can I omit there in this sentence as follow?

> It does not matter how many days are in a week.

Comment: I think you need it there because without it your second sentence retains a structure of a question while it's not a question.
Question: "How many days are in a week?"
Not a question: "Sometimes I wonder how many days there are in a week."

Comment: I cannot see any difference in meaning between the two statements. (Google *the existential there* for background)

Comment: This an existential construction with a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question). The meaning is the same in both: "The answer to the question 'How many days are (there) in a week? doesn't matter'".

Comment: What a great and interesting question!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence sounds better with *there*, but yes, both are correct.

The former is analogous to "How many days are there in a week?"; the latter, to "How many days are in a week?"

For that matter, the former is analogous to "There are seven days in a week", the latter to ["Seven days are in a week"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seven+days+are+in+a+week%22). (But personally I find "Seven days are in a week" to be *very* awkward, whereas the versions with "how many" are only *somewhat* awkward IMHO.)